# RandomizedSearchCv results in Attribute Error

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

After execution of fit() on RandomizedSearchCv:

```
        tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(strip_accents=None,lowercase=False,preprocessor=None)
        param_grid = 
            {'vect__ngram_range': [(1,1)],'vect__stop_words': [stop, None],
                       'vect__tokenizer': [tokenizer, tokenizer_porter],
                       'clf__penalty': ['l1', 'l2'],
            'clf__C': [1.0, 10.0, 100.0]},
lr_tfidf = Pipeline([('vect', tfidf),('clf',LogisticRegression(random_state=0))])
gs_lr_tfidf = RandomizedSearchCV(lr_tfidf,param_grid,cv=5,n_jobs=1)
gs_lr_tfidf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I get following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/pythonprojectraschka/ch08/ch08-2.py", line 95, in <module>
    gs_lr_tfidf.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\grid_search.py", line 996, in fit
    return self._fit(X, y, sampled_params)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\grid_search.py", line 553, in _fit
    for parameters in parameter_iterable
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 800, in __call__
    while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 653, in dispatch_one_batch
    tasks = BatchedCalls(itertools.islice(iterator, batch_size))
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.items = list(iterator_slice)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\grid_search.py", line 549, in <genexpr>
    delayed(_fit_and_score)(clone(base_estimator), X, y, self.scorer_,
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\grid_search.py", line 223, in __iter__
    for v in self.param_distributions.values()])
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

But for instance,Pipeline(lr_tfidf) is executed without any problem:

```
lr_tfidf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

What may be the reasons? X_train(text) and y_train(binary) are proper(I guess) numpy arrays.

Whole code with dataset:
https://github.com/kuba2111/untitled12

Comment: Where did this 'values' come from ? Can you explain it ? Does this this error persist if you remove the n_jobs argument ?

Comment: n_jobs argument doesnt change anything. X-train and y_train  are Pandas Series converted to numpy arrays with .values() method. I can provide whole code, if neccessary(sorry I am newbie in python)

Comment: can you try `print type(X_train)`and `print type(y_train)` ?

Comment: <class 'numpy.ndarray'> . So this is not the root of problem. I guess that this may be a bug associated with parallel processing  (n_jobs).  https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2889 I use windows also but in my case n_jobs=1(so it shouldnt trigger any problems)

Comment: try to provide the full code and toy example so people can just copy-paste and test your code easily

Comment: Thanks for help, I provided code in question.

Comment: Support for list of dict by `RandomizedSearchCV` is ongoing https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/12728.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you're using a [RandomizedSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.RandomizedSearchCV.html#examples-using-sklearn-grid-search-randomizedsearchcv) instead of [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV).
So it looks like it thinks that one of the parameters is a distribution and try to sample from this dstribution.

So if you're okay with an exhaustive search over all the parameters using GridSearchCV is your solution.

[image]

Comment: I've just run your code with gridsearchcv and it works for me.

Comment: thanks very much for help :) You're obviously right.